# Laggy animations (tab bar/pager) with react-native

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, react-native

I have a quite typical problem of laggy animations during component rendering. However, as far as I understand, the common solutions I found in the documentation of react-native cannot be applied to my use case.

Let me explain: I have a tab pager implemented with (i) a ViewPagerAndroid containing a set of pages and (ii) a tab bar composed of a set of touchables and a line (Animated.View) that moves (translateX transform) when the pager X-scroll value changes.

Each page component follows the same logic:

- when componentDidMount is called, it triggers a network call for loading data
- once the data are loaded, the state is updated with the new data and the component is rerendered
- the render method simply returns a FlatList that displays the loaded data (20 items only)

My problem is: if the user clicks on a tab while the pages are rendered, the animations are horribly laggy. Given that the animation and the rerendering are performed on the UI thread, I'm guessing that they are competing in some way.

I eliminated various causes, but wasn't able to find a proper solution to keep the animation fluid:

- I replaced the network call with hardcoded data and a simple timeout; the UI is still laggy when the pages are rerendered
- I tried to improve the rerendering time, but the FlatList is quite slow even using pure components.
- I tried in release mode and there is no differences
- The problem occurs also on a physical device (Nexus 5X, which is quite powerful)
- It's not specific to my implementation, I tried github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view and github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager
- I know about InteractionManager and TimerMixin.requestAnimationFrame, but it's useless in my case: when the rendering is started, the user can still click on the tab bar buttons and it's not an option to wait the end of the render (laggy).

I uploaded my code in a github repository (https://github.com/benjaminbillet/tabbartest), in case you want to have more details. It's quite straightforward, but don't hesitate to ask me more details.

Some additional information:

- react-native 0.46.4
- node 8.2.0
- npm 5.3.0
- tried only on Android.

Do you think I should fill a bug report?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT-1** Here is a simplified version of the animation code:

```
render() {
  const underlineStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: this.tabWidth,
    height: underlineHeight,
    backgroundColor: underlineColor,
    transform: [{
      translateX: this.pagerScrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0, this.tabWidth],
      }),
    }],
  };

  return (
    <View style={[styles.tabs, style]}>
      ...
      <Animated.View style={underlineStyle} />
    </View>
  );
}

onPageScroll(offset) {
  const { offset, position } = e.nativeEvent;
  this.pagerScrollX.setValue(position + offset);
}
```

Comment: That's way too much code for us to read. Please add the relevant animation code that is laggy. Also did you hear about native driver animation and did you try them?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Regarding the native driver, if I understand well, I would have to use Animation.event() to map the scroll to the Animated.Value. However, the event passed to ViewPagerAndroid#onPageScroll() is composed of two parts, position and offset, that I must combine to get the actual scroll (http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/viewpagerandroid.html#onpagescroll). Does Animated.event() enable me to create such operation?

Comment: Regarding the code, I'm not sur how to simplify this example (it's actually a simplified version of my app, I kept and rewrote only the relevant code); you can't see the problem without all the components. However, I edited my question with a simplified example of the animation code.

Comment: BTW, I read https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated.html and they state that the native driver it is used "for navigation animations in the newly released React Navigation library", but react-navigation has exactly the same problem than me with their tab bars.

Comment: I'm not sure about what they do with the tab bar, but the native driver animations will run on a separate thread and should not be in competition with your js code... As for Animated.event() - it maps a single value from the payload to an animated value. If you need more than one then I don't think I have an immediate solution, but I'll think about it.

Comment: I'm digging a little bit into it. There is something called Animation.add that would help me to combine two animated values into one (hoping that the whole thing would be offloaded to the native code through the native driver). Anyway, I'm not sure that the ViewPagerAndroid is compatible with the native driver.
I will test this and let you know if it helped.

Comment: Actually, it's a more general problem than just animation. Even if I chose to remove the animation, there is still a lag when the user clicks on a tab while the pager content is rendering.